# Drupal: Can't access any link within "Administer" but normal user access works well

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm new to Drupal and am experiencing this strange problem with my testing Drupal 6.19 site:

I've installed and enabled some custom theme ("acquia_marina"), and now strange things happen:

1) I can login/logout both as admin and as normal users
2) I can access Forums/Blogs from the primary links, and by clicking on them I can access their content
3) However, logged in as adminstrator, when I click on ANY link within "Administer", such as "Content management -> Books", or "Site building -> Modules", I see nothing! The resulting page is a totally blank page without any content!

I'm quite scared about this issue, as I can't even access "Administer -> Reports". Not being able to control (or at least have an over about) what's going on inside my Drupal site is quite scaring!

Has anyone encountered similar problems? More important, can anyone provide hints how to troubleshoot problem if you don't have access to "Administer -> Reports"?

thanks in advance!

--tumer

Lessons learned: always back up before installing/enabling contributed modules!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're just a getting a blank screen without any information. CurtainDog's suggestion of upping the memory limit is a good idea but the WSOD (White Screen of Death) might be caused due to other reasons. Try changing the memory limit and if it still doesn't work try the below. (Caution: Proceed carefully as you'll be making manual changes to your database. If you don't feel comfortable doing this then DONT :-) ! )

Possible fixes:

1. If you have the Administration menu module installed try flushing all caches and see if that makes any difference? (Flush all caches is available under the drop down to the left of `Content Management`)
2. If that does not help, empty (and NOT remove) all tables in the database whose name starts with cache e.g. cache, cache_menu, cache_block etc. You can do this using phpmyadmin
3. If that does not help you can try disabling different modules manually from the `system` table using phpmyadmin. Simply set the 'status' field to `0` to disable the module or theme. Be sure to clear the cache after doing that.
4. You might also need to changing the default theme manually -- its slightly more tricky. You will need to access the `variable` table and change the `theme_default` variable from `s:13:"acquia_marina";` to something like `s:7:"garland";`. Make sure that the line corresponding to `themes/garland/garland.info` has `status` set to `1` in the `system` table. Don't forget to clear the caches after making this change!

Comment: thanks NoParrots. It turned out to be a custom theme/module problem. I disable one of the custom modules (by setting its status column to 0 in the "system" table), and the site admin pages are back. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just up your php memory limit. When you are logged in as the Admin you are triggering a couple of extra functions that push you over the memory limit, which in turn causes PHP's White Screen of Death. There are several options available to you, just pick one that you feel comfortable with and your server config allows.

Here's the link: http://drupal.org/node/207036